# jquery effect() function not recognized

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem creating a bounce effect on an image with jQuery effect() function.
Actually is use this code (code after calling the jQuery library):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#arrow-disclaimer').bind('mouseenter', function(){
  $(this).effect('bounce',500);
  });
});
```

```html
//Here there isn't the jQuery library, but in the page is included before jqueryUI

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style-disclaimer.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/i18n/jquery-ui-i18n.js"></script>
<a href="#disclaimer-p">
  <img src="images/arrow483.png" id="arrow-disclaimer" />
</a>
```

Could someone tell me why i get this error?

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).effect is not a function

Comment: jQuery-UI require jQuery and jQuery should be loaded before all it's dependants.

Comment: Try defining jquery before jquery-ui

Comment: i've updated the post, it doesn't function anyway

Comment: Try using jQuery() instead of $() if you have other JS libraries included

Comment: are you sure, that `this` is correct here?

Comment: I think yes, i saw that in another post

Comment: You have to provide a MCVE, not just letting us guessing what you are doing or not...

Comment: i told that i used the code above.. and there is a comment wich tell: Here there isn't the jQuery library, but in the page is included before jqueryUI

Comment: @GiuseppeDePaola Oh my bad, i missed your comment: `//Here there isn't the jquery library, but in the page is included before jqueryUI`  That's why you shouldn't include this kind of info as comment, and better provide the relevant code. Again, i'm sorry

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. You need to load jQuery to use jQuery-ui or any other dependant plugin
2. You're using `jquery-ui-i18n` which is used for internationalization only. You need to include `jquery-ui` main library and **if** you want to use i18n, include it after jquery-ui.
3. [`bind`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) is deprecated in jQuery version 1.7, use [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#arrow-disclaimer').on('mouseenter', function() {
    $(this).effect('bounce', 500);
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<a href="#disclaimer-p">
  <img src="images/arrow483.png" id="arrow-disclaimer" />
</a>
```

Comment: Good point but if OP isn't including jQuery UI, including jquery-ui-i18n would throw an error

Comment: Hey @A.Wolff Mentioned in #2 _You need to include jquery-ui main library and if you want to use i18n, include it after jquery-ui._

Comment: It works, thank.. but now the image that i've animated goes to the left side of the page during the animation, and then it go back to the center..can it be a problem with the div of 100% of width?

Comment: @GiuseppeDePaola That should be happening because of CSS styles, can  you create live demo

Comment: @Tushar Ya, i get your point but this was what i mean, if OP wasn't including jQuery UI, just including jquery-ui-i18n would throw an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'regional' of undefined`. Now OP said it was part of problem, so he just ommit to say there was other error... What can we say?!... ;)

Comment: @Tushar yes it was a css problem. Just needed a position: absolute;